# solution of nonlinear first order system of ode

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to check the solution of nonlinear first order system of ode, for example I want to see when its solution is increasing or decreasing (by coefficient matrix)? Is there a method for this check? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A good method is to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}(\|u\|^2)=\frac{d}{dt}(\|(x,y)\|^2)=2x\dot{x}+2y\dot{y}$, this will tell you if your solution is increasing or decreasing in magnitude, but you cannot say if a solution is increasing or decreasing in $2$ dimensions or higher, because you cannot say if one vector is larger than another.

So your example is:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
x' = xy+z \\
y' = yz+x\\
z' =  z+x+y\end{array}\right \}$

The solution is $u(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$

$\frac{d}{dt}(\|u\|^2)=\frac{d}{dt}(\|(x,y,z)\|^2)=2xx'+2yy'+2zz'$

$=2(x(xy+z)+y(yz+x)+z(z+x+y))$

Comment: could you please tell me what is the u? is it coefficient matrix? My system is for example $y'=xy+z,x'=yz+x,z'=z+x+y$

Comment: @user151566 in your  case $u$ is the vector $u=(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Yeah sorry should have said, $u$is your solution, so as user said, in your case $u=(x,y,z)$

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand the last sentence that you say @ellya. could you please write an example?

Comment: @user151566, see my edit, also in my previous comment, I meant "so as TZakrevskiy said"

Comment: @ellya I know that but I don't understand the sentence from but to end of it.

Comment: Which sentence sorry? is it one of the comments, or in my answer?

Comment: I'm very sorry for giving your time.But I don't understand this sentence: but you cannot say if a solution is increasing or decreasing in 2 dimensions or higher, because you cannot say if one vector is larger than another

Comment: Oh I see!, okay well say $a,b\in\Bbb R$, then we can say $a\le b$ or $b\le a$, but if we have two vectors $(x_1,y_1)^T,(x_2,y_2)^T$, we cannot say $(x_1,y_1)^T\le(x_2,y_2)^T$ or $(x_1,y_1)^T\ge(x_2,y_2)^T$, and since your solution is a vector, you cannot say if is increasing or decreasing, because you cannot compare two vectors in that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot.By this method $\frac{d}{dt}(\|u\|^2)$. can I compare $x_1$ and $x_2$ without any attention to other variables?

Comment: with this you can see if the norm of the solution is increasing or decreasing, allowing you to compare the norm of the solution at different times.

Comment: Thanks and the last question.Could you please a reference about this method to me?